Assign model with raw SQL query
I have raw SQL query as:
var queryResult = await (await GetDbContextAsync()).Database.SqlQuery<ClaimBatch>(@$"SELECT [CB].[Id], [CB].[TenantId], [InterchangeControlNumber], [BatchIdentifier], [BatchDate], [SenderIdentifier], [ReceiverIdentifier], [AgencyIdentifier], [ReceivedDate], [CreationTime], [CreatorId], [LastModificationTime]
,[LastModifierId], [Filename], [ProcessingRuleSetId], [ProcessingStatus], [SourceClaimBatchId], [ProcessingResultMessage], [ProcessingMethod], [CBE].Id, [CBE].ClaimBatchId, [CBE].[Description],
[CBE].TenantId, [CBE].[TimeStamp], [CBE].[Type] FROM [CmClaimBatch] AS [CB]
LEFT JOIN [CmClaimBatchEvent] AS [CBE] ON [CB].[Id] = [CBE].[ClaimBatchId]
")
.ToListAsync();

But this is throwing an error:

The property 'ClaimBatch.EventHistory' of type 'IList' appears to be a navigation to another entity type. Navigations are not supported when using 'SqlQuery". Either include this type in the model and use 'FromSql' for the query, or ignore this property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute.

Because that event history is a list inside the ClaimBatch entity:
public IList<ClaimBatchEvent> EventHistory { get; set; }

How can I assign or map that list if I'm getting those entity properties in the left join?
UPDATE
From the comments below, I made some modifications:
var context = await GetDbContextAsync();

var claimBatch = context.ClaimBatch
               .FromSql(@$"
        SELECT 
            [CB].[Id] AS ClaimBatchId, 
            [CB].[TenantId],
            [CB].[InterchangeControlNumber], 
            [CB].[BatchIdentifier], 
            [CB].[BatchDate], 
            [CB].[SenderIdentifier], 
            [CB].[ReceiverIdentifier], 
            [CB].[AgencyIdentifier], 
            [CB].[ReceivedDate], 
            [CB].[ConcurrencyStamp],
            [CB].[ExtraProperties], 
            [CB].[CreationTime], 
            [CB].[CreatorId], 
            [CB].[LastModificationTime],
            [CB].[LastModifierId], 
            [CB].[Filename], 
            [CB].[ProcessingRuleSetId], 
            [CB].[ProcessingStatus], 
            [CB].[SourceClaimBatchId], 
            [CB].[ProcessingResultMessage], 
            [CB].[ProcessingMethod], 
            [CBE].[Id] AS EventId, 
            [CBE].[Description],
            [CBE].[TenantId],
            [CBE].[TimeStamp], 
            [CBE].[Type] 
        FROM 
            [CmClaimBatch] AS [CB]
        LEFT JOIN 
            [CmClaimBatchEvent] AS [CBE] ON [CB].[Id] = [CBE].[ClaimBatchId]
    ")
               .ToList();

I have a claimBatch entity that has the property TenantId, but inside that claimBatch entity, I have a list of EventHistory entities, and that one also has the same TenantId property, so for the ClaimBatch entity corresponds to the [CB].[TenantId] and for the event history is the [CBE].[TenantId], but when I try to run this code, it throws an error:

The column 'TenantId' was specified multiple times for 'd'.

How can I specify which tenant ID is for which entity?

Why are you using SqlQuery at all and just loading the entities via their DbSet? I don't see anything in that query that justifies custom SQL. If you want to selectively populate a subset of values instead of entire entities, use projection (Select)

That's just the beginning of a long complex query; that's why I started writing it as sqlQuery and not with linq @StevePy

It's extremely rare to need to go down to SQL, The Linq implementation is quite powerful, flexible, and performant. But as the exception says, you will likely have more luck with the DbSet<TEntity>.FromSql rather than Database.SqlQuery<T>  if you're convinced you need to go down to SQL. SqlQuery is not normally used for retrieving entities, rather values or DTOs.

I tried, but now I'm facing more issues, I just updated my question @StevePy

Chances are you are going to need to structure the query similar to how EF builds it for Linq. Even then it may not be enough to populate the related entities like eager loading. Update the LEFT JOIN ti include the columns in the inner SELECT. I..e. LEFT JOIN ( SELECT cbe.ClaimBatchId, cbe.TenantId, .... FROM CmClaimBatchEvent cbe) AS CBE ON CB.Id = CBE.ClaimBatchId...
The Linq implementation does all of this automatically so I would strongly recommend using that first and then addressing any possible limitation you might come across.

One query, one entity. But you can then compose the IQueryable<> further. context.ClaimBatch.FromSqlRaw("select * from CmClaimBatch [where complex critieria]").Include(b => b.CmClaimBatchEvent). But if you can write the where clause via linq, you should do that. Or create a separate entity just for this view. Also; Keyless entities can define navigations to parent objects, but not dependents.

So you could define a view entity with just FK's and Navigation properties, context.[Entity].FromSqlRaw("select ClaimBatchId, Id, OtherId from CmClaimBatchEvent ....").Include(m => m.CmClaimBatch).Include(m => m.CmClaimBatchEvent).

The column 'TenantId' was specified multiple times for 'd'. You could try aliasing your columns like this: SELECT .... [CBE].[TenantId], AS EventTenantId ... 
